# insertbefore and find the css class - js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding some element with content before this div

```
<div id="before_this">
  blablabla
</div>
```

my js:

```
$('<p class="comment"> test <small> date </small></p>').insertBefore('#before_this').find('.comment');
```

but the class `comment` properties wont be applied to new added element.

how can I achieve this in jquery?

Comment: you can downvote me how much you want, but please guide me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is that? *It is applied*, since you create a new element `<p>` with class `.comment`. However `.find()` won't work, because there are no descendants of the `<p>`, which have class `.comment`.

If you need to work with the inserted element, go on and use chaining:

```
$("<p class='comment'>...</p>").insertBefore("#before_this").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: i tried with font-size: `.css("font-size","12px");` but not working

Comment: Why not just use css?  `p.comment {font-size: 12px;}`

Answer (score 2):

`insertBefore` returns the collection on which it was called. This collection in your example is already `p.comment`.

Try this in console and you'll see the `p.comment` jQuery object:

```
var $p = $('<p class="comment"> test <small> date </small></p>').insertBefore('#before_this');

console.log($p); // p.comment jQ object
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.find()` at the end looks for an element inside the selected element.  Since the element you are looking for is the selected element, this will never work. (In other words, there are no descendants of `p.comment` that have class "comment.")

If what you want to do is select the element you've just created, it's already selected.

```
var selectedElement = $('<p class="comment"> test <small> date </small></p>').insertBefore('#before_this');
// selectedElement === $('p.comment');
```

If you want the class name, use the following instead:

```
$('<p class="comment"> test <small> date </small></p>').insertBefore('#before_this').attr('class');
```

But of course that makes no sense since you already know that the class of the element you created and gave a class of "comment" to will be "comment"!